# how to pass json array in params to get rest api in nodejs

Tags: node.js, arrays, rest, get

I have one GET API which is having array in the input.
I want to call that API through in my node.js project.
I have tried many options but none worked.
This is my REST Request.

```
let request = await Request.get(
    `url?arr=1234,1235`,
    {
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json" }
    }
    );
```

But getting bad request.

This is the CURL I received.

```
curl --location --request GET 'url' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '
{
    "arr":["1234","1235"]
}
```

Please help.

I tried with POST request instead of GET.

I tried `url?arr[]=1234,1235`

I tried `url?arr=["1234","1235"]`

I tried `url?arr="1234","1235"`

I tried `url?params={arr:["12551138844"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done in several different ways. There is no set standard.

You could do it with `url?arr=1234,1235`, but you need to make sure that your backend parses the query parameter accordingly with something like `arr = req.query.arr?.split(',')`.

Keep in mind that URL query parameters are just strings and parsing them is up to the backend. If you are using an API you should check its documentation. Different APIs have different URL parameter format requirements. If you make the API yourself you should make sure you are parsing the data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `node:querystring` module to build query params. I assume you are using commonJS if you use ESM simple change the import.

According to [RFC 7231 section 3.1.5.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5),

**`Content-Type`** HTTP header should be set only for PUT and POST requests, doesn't required for GET request

```
const queryBuilder = require('node:querystring');
const params = queryBuilder.stringify({arr:[1,2]}); // gives arr=1&arr=2

let request = await Request.get('url?'+params);
```

[NODEJS DOC](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html)